# htaccess redirect subdirectory to another subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, cpanel, http-redirect

I have to redirect my URLs from /blog.html/* to /blog/* due to Seo issues.
Looking for .htaccess rule for that

```
RewriteRule ^blog.html/?(.*)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

this is already tried

I tried this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?folderA/(.*)$ /folderB/$1 [R,L]
```

but this only redirects domain/blog.html to domain/blog but not domain/blog.html/anyblog to domain/blog/anyblog

my website is hosted on cpanel and blog is added via WordPress, so .httaccess files for both the site are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog.html/(.*)$ http://abcd.com/blog/$1
```

This should work.